# How can I prevent user data being cached and showing the wrong username?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I have built a Drupal 8 site, we are showing the user name and last name on a block, this is my code on preprocess from .theme file:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

$firstname = $user->get('field_firstname')->value;

$firstname = $firstname;
$variables['firstname'] = $firstname;
```

Then in the block im doing: `Hello {{ firstname }}`

And it shows the last user, not mine. When I do `drush cr` then I get the correct name, why? How can I fix this and already display the right username?

Comment: add to your block class this method `public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }`

Comment: not sure what you mean, im using this on the _preprocess(&$variables, $hook) { of the theme..

Comment: you process your block with THEME_preprocess_block ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving the user name from the current context and the user entity, but then you make it a dumb string value to pass it to the template. Include the cache metadata to define where this value is coming from and under which circumstances it could change:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$firstname = $user->get('field_firstname')->value;

$variables['firstname'] = [
  '#plain_text' => $firstname,
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => ['user'],
    'tags' => $user->getCacheTags(),
  ],
];
```

More info https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays

Comment: Adding this cache context should address exactly this problem, see the linked docs.

Comment: We used a programmatically generated custom block to solve a similar problem. See the last answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549174/theme-is-caching-previous-user-name/74871226#74871226 for details.